# How can i check where is missing closing tag in my SASS / SCSS

Tags: sass

If i have a fairly large document in SCSS, and somewhere i missed the closing tag, is there any program or service or output (console log) code to check where is the missing closing tag?
(Im using SASSY with drupal PHP preprocessor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sass` binary built in to [the actual Sass library](http://sass-lang.com/) will report syntax errors.

```
$ cat broken.scss
html {
    display: block;
    .orange {
        color: orange;
}
$ sass broken.scss
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
        on line 6 of broken.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

You can install `sass` with `gem install sass` as long as Ruby is installed. That will install the latest version of `sass`.

If you don’t already have Ruby installed, just install it on your development machine. On Windows, use the [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/). On Mac, use the built-in old version of Ruby, or install a newer version with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) using `brew install ruby`. On Linux, search for “ruby” in your package manager.

If you mean that you want a program to tell you “the closing `}` you’re missing should go between `color: orange;` and `}`, I doubt there is one. Deciding exactly where the `}` would require making assumptions about indentation and other formatting of the code, so any program someone has written for that probably only works with their code. In the example code, there is no general and automatic way to tell if `color: orange;` was supposed to be inside `.orange` or inside `html`.

Comment: thanks! yes i have seen that when using ruby, but like i said im using drupal with php preprocessor so i dont really get anything. So ya, i would be happy for any sort of information. I will edit my question to highlight the PHP preprocessor in use.

Comment: @petergus You could install Ruby on your development machine, just for the purposes of running `sass`. See my edit with installation instructions. When you’ve installed `sass`, just find where your `.scss` or `.sass` file is, or copy your styles into a new file if your styles are embedded in another file, and run `sass` on it.